# DataTables Multi Filter Select Column Headers in Select?

Tags: jquery, datatables

Using the [DataTables Multi Filter Select](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html) switched to show in the header vs the footer, I'd like to keep the header column titles in place or at least as the first option in my select list:

```
<option value="" disabled selected hidden>THIS COL HEADER TITLE</option>
```

However, I am not able to get the column header.

Here is the filter:

```
$('#requests-table').DataTable({
        pagingType: "full_numbers",
        bSort: false,
        initComplete: function() {
            //console.log(this.api().columns());
            var columns = this.api().columns();
            columns[0].shift();
            //console.log(this.api().columns());
            columns.every(function() {
                var column = this;
                //console.log(this);
                var select = $('<select class="max-width-100"><option value=""></option></select>')
                    .appendTo($(column.header()).empty())
                    .on('change', function() {
                        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                            $(this).val()
                        );

                        column
                            .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
                            .draw();
                    });

                column.data().unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {
                    select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
                });
            });
        }
    });
```

This seems like the answer:

```
var idx = table.cell( this ).index().column;
    var title = table.column( idx ).header();
```

...but I cannot get it to work in here.

I would then have my option like so for each col th:

```
<option value="" disabled selected hidden>'+ title +'</option>
```

Thoughts or help?

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
var select = $('<select class="max-width-100"><option value=""></option></select>')
```

with

```
var select = $('<select><option value="">' + $(this.header()).html() + '</option></select>')
```